# I would like to test for isometric growth in fish using b value from linear regression against a b value of 3 using t test

Tags: regression, r, hypothesis-testing, biostatistics

I have data on length/weight for male fish and want to compare by $b$ value for slope of regression against 3 to test for isometric growth. I tried using `hoCoef` fucntion also

```r
hoCoef(lm1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the lavaan package in R, you could constrain (fix) the regression slope (b) to any value of your choice (e.g., to 3) and then test the constrained regression model against your data using a model chi-square goodness of fit test with 1 degree of freedom. A statistically significant chi-square value would indicate that the constrained model with the fixed slope is rejected (incorrect).

```r
library(lavaan)

REGRESSION <- 'Y ~ 3*X'

fit <- sem(model=REGRESSION, data=data, estimator="ml", missing="fiml")

summary(fit, fit.measures=TRUE, standardized=TRUE, rsquare=TRUE)
```